# Fragment button not interactive

Tags: java, android

So my problem is that I want to add method for button placed in fragment. This works perfectly well in other activity/fragment, but here I can't get it clicked. I can however launch buttonReference.callOnClick() and it does work. Just can't get response by clicking on it in UI.
This code seems super similar to one that works well, so this something beyond attached code, but I'd appreciate any hints what can be wrong.

```
public class PhoneNrFragment extends Fragment {

EditText phoneNr;
TextView areaNr;
Button selectArea;

public PhoneNrFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phone_nr_fragment, container, false);
    selectArea = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.phone_nr_frag_choose_area_btn);
    selectArea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public  void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("Login", "PhoneNrFragment on arrow button clicked");
        }
    });
    Log.v("Login", "PhoneNrFragment onCreateView changeArea listener attached");
    phoneNr = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.phone_nr_frag_nr_input);
    areaNr = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.phone_nr_frag_area_nr);

    return view;
}

//this does work
public void clickDumbButtonByCode() {
    Log.v("Login", "click called from code");
    selectArea.callOnClick();
}
```

}

//here is the activity I'm using with this fragment:
    PhoneNrFragment phoneNrFragment;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    //SIGN_IN
    Button signInBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_sign_in_btn);
    signInBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onClick signInBtn");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onClickSignIn() not implemented", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    //SIGN_UP
    Button signUpBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_sign_up_btn);
    signUpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public  void  onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onClick signUpBtn");
            phoneNrFragment.clickDumbButtonByCode();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onClickSignUp() not implemented", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    });
    //FORGET_PASSWORD
    Button forgottenPassBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.remind_password_btn);
    forgottenPassBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public  void  onClick(View v) {
           Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onClick forgottenPassBtn");
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onClickFrogottenPassword", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
           SplashActivity.SwitchView(getBaseContext(), LostPasswordActivity.class);
       }
    });
    //PHONE_NR_FRAGMENT
    FragmentTransaction fragInjection = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    phoneNrFragment = new PhoneNrFragment();
    fragInjection.replace( R.id.login_phone_nr_fragment, phoneNrFragment).commit();
}
}
//there is nothing more in it except stored reference to this fragment
```

And here is fragment layout:

```
<!-- AREA_CHOOSE_LINE -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/phone_nr_frag_area_line"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/phone_nr_frag_nr_line"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/phone_nr_frag_nr_line"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/phone_nr_frag_nr_line"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TextView
        android:text="Hong Kong"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/phone_nr_frag_area_name"
        tools:text="Select Area"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_width="243dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="27dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/phone_nr_frag_choose_area_btn"
        android:background="@drawable/black_right_arrow"/>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- PHONE_NR_LINE -->
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/phone_nr_frag_nr_line"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <!-- area_number -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/phone_nr_frag_area_nr"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:background="@drawable/login_short_input_field"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <!-- phone_number -->
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/phone_nr_frag_nr_input"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/login_phone_field"
        android:paddingLeft="26dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong. Please bear in mind that calling this button from code does work. I'm quite new to Android so I could be doing something obviously wrong. 
Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: one hint. I have no idea if it's matters, but I'm using: import android.app.Fragment; instead of android.support.v4.app.Fragment; because I could not create FragmentTransaction using android.support.v4.app.Fragment.

Comment: for which button in you code/layout you are not getting callback

Comment: As pointed out below, why are you referencing the activitity when getting the button reference? Use the inflated view to do so as expected and report back to us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

relpace  `selectArea = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.phone_nr_frag_choose_area_btn);`
with

```
selectArea = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.phone_nr_frag_choose_area_btn);
```

Comment: Thanks - that made it.